# Consulta para retornar o valor que vem antes de um carácter específico

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada `answer`  que é preenchida com respostas para determinadas perguntas, cada resposta normalmente começa com a letra que seria a resposta, por exemplo: `a)..., b)..., c)... ou d)...,` o problema é que nem sempre começa assim, pode acontecer de começar com um código `html` para depois vir a letra de resposta, pode vir assim `<p>a)...`

Gostaria de uma query que retorne apenas a letra que vem antes do fecha parêntesis `)`, lembrando também que deve pegar apenas o valor que antecede o primeiro parênteses, caso na resposta possa surgir outros parênteses.

Estou usando assim:

```
Select substr(answer,1,1) AS resposta
```

Mas não serve caso venha algo mais antes da letra de resposta.

Comment: acho que o ideal seria armazenar a alternativa em outra coluna, facilitaria, mas... dê uma olhada no `POSITION` https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-position-function.php

Comment: @RovannLinhalis isso é verdade, esse banco é do moodle, já fucei e não tem uma tabela com estas respostas, mas apenas com a resposta completa, estas letras eu adiciono para gerar um gabarito, foi a única forma que encontrei

Comment: Caso conheça expressão regular, pode usar uma função no MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue a ideia comentada por [Rovann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69359/rovann-linhalis), usa o **[`position()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-position-function.php)**:

SELECT substr (coluna_answer, (POSITION(")" IN coluna_answer) - 1), 1) AS resposta

Comment: Testando aqui...

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!
Obrigado rLinhares.